# Expo Notification Error in ios [Error: Another async call to this method is in progress. Await the first Promise.]

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

Please provide the following:

1. SDK Version: "^42.0.0",
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS
3. Add the appropriate "Tag" based on what Expo library you have a question on.

Hello,

> [expo-notifications] Error encountered while updating server registration with latest device push token., [Error: Another async call to this method is in progress. Await the first Promise.]

This error often occurs in expo app. And always occurs in build ios app.

Using the following code:

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync()
    let finalStatus = existingStatus
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync({
        ios: {
          allowAlert: true,
          allowBadge: true,
          allowSound: true,
          allowAnnouncements: true,
        },
      })
      finalStatus = status
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      console.log('noti cancel')
      return
    }
    // token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data

    try {
      await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync().then((res) => {
        console.log('getExpoPUshTokenAsync >> ', res)
        token = res.data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('getExpoPushTokenAsync error >> ', err)
    }
  } else {
    Alert.alert(
    'Must use physical device for Push Notifications'
    )
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    })
  }

  return token
}
```

I have received a new credential, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Hi, It was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly, but I think it was probably caused by keys being registered to multiple channels or different projects. I checked at the time using a php server, logging with `echo` to the suspect part of the vendor → alymosul → exponent-server-sdk-php → lib → Expo.php file.
Sorry for not being of much help.